# Anylogic Sensitivity Analysis chart legend

Tags: anylogic

I was able to successfully create a sensitivty analysis, but unfortunately, as can be seen in the picture, the legend has a random arrangement. But I would like to have an ascending order.

[Sensitivity Analysis with random legend order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naG9k.png)

After Simulation Run:

```
Color color = lerpColor( (getCurrentIteration() - 1) / (double) (getMaximumIterations() - 1), blue, red );
chart0.addDataSet( root.childDS, format( root.childgoal ), color, true, Chart.INTERPOLATION_LINEAR, 1, Chart.POINT_NONE );
```

The input dataset is in ascending order.
I tried it with sortAscending. Unfortunately it did not work.

Thank you very much for suggestions on how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your runs finish quasi-randomly and you simply add datasets when a run is finished.

To overcome this, either run in sequential mode (turn off "parallel evaluations" in the experiment settings).

Or do this:

- add a collection of type `LinkedHashMap` with key as `Integer`, value as `DataSet`, name it `myCol`
- in the "After Simulation Run" code, do this after your line to define the color:

---

```
myCol.put(getCurrentIteration(), root.childDS);
chart0.removeAll(); // maybe use .clearAll(), cant remember
for (int currIt : myCol.keySet()) {
    chart0.addDataSet(myCol.get(currIt), ...); // add other args as usual
}
```

---

You may need to wiggle with the code itself, just writing from memory here, use the API and help if you get stuck

Comment: Thank you very much. 
"Allow parallel evaluations" was activated by default. Deactivating this solved my problem.